# What are the uniformly minimum variance unbiased estimators (UMVUE) for the minimum and maximum parameters of a PERT distribution?

Tags: unbiased-estimator, beta-distribution, umvue, minimum-variance

I believe the answers to this question are the sample minimum and the sample maximum, but I have not been able to find a reference or proof of this.

Comment: Because the maximum of any sample is almost surely less than the upper limit and the minimum is almost surely greater than the lower limit, *both are biased.*

Comment: That makes complete sense.

Comment: Do you have some reason to believe that an UMVUE exists for this family of distributions? (I suspect it does, but I'm not sure. I've never actually thought about this family.)